# How to use Boost.Coroutine in a fashion similar to Unity3D Coroutine in terms of sleep?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

How to use [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/symmetric.html) in a fashion similar to [Unity3D Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in terms of sleep for X milliseconds? Generally we want having an array of corutines allow them to forvard next execution futher in time using some alternative of WaitForSeconds object as yield return. Is there any utilety for such things in Boost.Coroutine or how to recreate effect from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Fiber has sleep function. see follow:

https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber

Boost.Fiber is wrapper of Boost.Coroutine for thread interface.

```
// <boost/fiber/operations.hpp>
namespace boost {
namespace this_fiber {
void sleep_until( fibers::clock_type::time_point const& sleep_time);

template< typename Rep, typename Period >
void sleep_for( chrono::duration< Rep, Period > const& timeout_duration)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the coroutine class using C++ 11 and boost coroutine2.
Usage of CoroBehaviour is very similar with MonoBehaviour of Unity like below:

```
#include "CoroBehaviour.h"
#include <iostream>

class ExampleClass : public CoroBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(coroutineA());
    }

    Enumerator coroutineA()
    {
        return [=](CoroPush& yield_return)
        {
            // wait for 1 second
            std::cout << "coroutineA created";
            yield_return(new WaitForSeconds(1.0f));
            yield_return(StartCoroutine(coroutineB()));
            std::cout << "coroutineA running again";
        };
    }

    Enumerator coroutineB()
    {
        return [=](CoroPush& yield_return)
        {
            std::cout << "coroutineB created";
            yield_return(new WaitForSeconds(2.5f));
            std::cout << "coroutineB enables coroutineA to run";
        };
    }
}
```

You can get the code from here: https://github.com/exawon/CoroBehaviour